In latest version of RestSharp from 106.12.0 to 111.3.0 has error Null reference exception at Execute #2242
Getting Error

at RestSharp.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.g__AddHeader|0_2(Parameter parameter, HttpHeaders httpHeaders)
at RestSharp.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.c__DisplayClass0_0.b__1(Parameter x)
at RestSharp.Extensions.CollectionExtensions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable1 items, Action1 action)
at RestSharp.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.AddHeaders(HttpRequestMessage message, RequestHeaders headers)
at RestSharp.RestClient.d__5.MoveNext()
at RestSharp.RestClient.d__1.MoveNext()
at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.c__DisplayClass1_01.b__0>d.MoveNext() at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.CustomSynchronizationContext.g__PostCallback|7_0>d.MoveNext() at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.CustomSynchronizationContext.Run() at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.RunSync(Func1 task)
at RestSharp.AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task)
at RestSharp.RestClientExtensions.Execute(IRestClient client, RestRequest request)

Code Snippet:
RestRequest request = GetRequestObject(alertNotificationTransfer);
RetryPolicy policy = Policy.HandleResult(x => x.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created)
.WaitAndRetry(myRetryCount, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(myWaitIntervalInSeconds));
var response = policy.Execute(() => myRestClient.Execute(request));
//...

internal RestRequest GetRequestObject(NotificationTransfer alertNotificationTransfer)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(GetEnvironmentVariable(myRelativeUrlKey), Method.Post);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddJsonBody(alertNotificationTransfer);
    return request;
}

I made changes in my code to RestResponse earlier it was IRestResponse as IRestResponse is depricated in latest version.

The stacktrace hints to async execution, while the code does not (at least not obviously). Why is that?

@Fildor In restclient.extensions we have
public static RestResponse Execute(this IRestClient client, RestRequest request)
=> AsyncHelpers.RunSync(() => client.ExecuteAsync(request));
This method is anyways calling async method

What's the type of Exception? And Sync-Over-Async is not the best of ideas. Why not go async all the way?

It looks like an issue in the code that isn't in the question, where you add a header with null value. The issue was closed as trying to add a header with null value will throw when the header parameter is added, not when the request is executed.
